# What would be a suitable name for a police force in a medieval fantasy setting?

Tags: police

The word 'Police' doesn't go much with a fantasy setting. In my opinion, names like '[Insert Country Name] Guards', Gendarme, Constabulary and Marechaussee would he more suitable. What is your opinion?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a good read to our [help]: we frown upon questions which are intrinsically opinion based, and your question falls in this category. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
 -  there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
 -   your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Comment: The word *police* doesn't go with medieval fantasy because there was no such thing as a police force in medieval times. There were private or public *guardsmen*, and there were (occasionally, and only in some places) armed patrols of *watchmen* attempting to keep the peace; but there was no organized force investigating crimes and attempting to detect and catch the criminals. You don't need to invent a *word*, bu rather you need to invent an entire organization; and you need to invent a source of funding for it, and you need to invent how it fit into the medieval society.

Comment: "Marechaussee" is modern Dutch and French for military police. Translating your story into these languages will require a different term. Someone responsable for keeping order in (late-)medieval Dutch cities was called a **Baljuw**, the officer was a **Drost**. The English word is **Bailiff**, can't find a translation for Drost.

Answer (score 1):

This question risks being closed for being 'fishing for lists of ideas.' I hope my answer is better on track:

The name **police** comes, through several steps, from the Greek **polis**, that is from the word *city*. The police force is the public order administration of the city. Some fantasy settings do have cities which are surprisingly modern in outlook, but by and large they are *feudal* systems. Who organized your police force, and whom are they loyal to?

- Is it a noble who *personally* holds the allegiance of the police force? Palace *guards*, castle *guards*, personal *retainers* ...
- For a city without a ruling noble, is it perhaps the guilds who are in power? City *guards* if there is a dedicated police, or perhaps city *watchmen* if they combine fire patrols at night.
- Often it was the citizens who did the policing, perhaps organized through the trade and craft guilds. That might imply no special name, since any artisan could be on duty for some nights each month.

Consider if the police guards the walls against outside attack, responds to a [hue and cry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue_and_cry) when a theft is in progress, or actually investigates crimes? Investigation was rather late, historically.

Comment: [Please try to refrain from answering questions that, literally, ask *what is your opinion?*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @elemtilas, I'm also trying to be polite to a new contributor, and I found it worthwhile to highlight the *personal* nature of loyalties for some of the time periods.

Answer (score -1):

I would certainly expect something like the Guard (King's, Royal, ) to fit the theme far more closely. Mostly because in such a setting political power is something personally possessed, by some right other than people agreeing you should have it. Instead you picked the right parents, or managed to seize it.

Comment: [Please try to refrain from answering questions that, literally, ask *what is your opinion?*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)